# H2 Power Steering Leak

Tags: power-steering, leak, power-steering-fluid, hummer, h2

2003 Hummer H2: So it looks I got a leak between two places. One between the gearbox housing and the steering column; and another between the housing and pitman arm. I was able to find these leaks by putting some UV dye for oil based fluids in the power steering reservoir and shining a UV light under the vehicle. I also had the splash shield off so I can have a better view.

I think I can replace both seals without replacing the whole housing. My question is, what parts or part kits do I need to solve this issue? It's unclear to me what I need to replace and it doesn't quite look like I can just replace a single seal.

I hope I put enough information in this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question, but have you priced up getting it swapped for a reconditioned unit?  They are often good value.